# How writing my own error in Ragel

Tags: c, ragel

Ragel is very easy. But how I can write my own error function?

I use loop:
main := |*
*|;

and if i get other data I need run my action? 
and how put error when my token is good gramar but not good good in semantic.

Comment: I never heart about Ragel before - sounds really  interesting. Googled "Ragel" and found [Ragel State Machine Compiler - User Guide](http://www.colm.net/files/ragel/ragel-guide-6.9.pdf) Chapter 3.2.3 is "Handling Errors". If you already read this you should state this in your question. Otherwise you will get angry feedback...

Comment: Semantical analysis is usually not part of the syntax description (grammar rules) but part of the associated actions (which you probably intend to write in C). There might be exceptions: e.g. operator precedence can be checked in actions but can even be expressed by the grammar rules itself.

Comment: @Scheff question is how implement error, give up if question is good